# AC adapter makes high pitched noise when a notebook is turned off or asleep

Tags: noise, adapter, laptop

When I put my notebook into sleep mode or turn it off the notebook's AC adapter starts making a high pitched noise. When the notebook is on the adapter doesn't make any noises. Could anybody explain why this happens? Is it OK or should I get another adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably caused by coils or components with piezo-electric properties (e.g. ceramic capacitors), which can produce audible noise when they are switched periodically.

Power supplies like the one of your laptop typically involve a switching regulator (SMPS) and some of those SMPS vary their switching frequency based on the current required by the load. That explains why you only hear the noise when the laptop is off or in standby: the SMPS needs to provide only little current and therefore likely reduces the switching frequency to a range that you can hear.

In that case, there is nothing to worry about. Actually, the reason why most PSUs don't make any audible noise is because their switching frequency is far above the range that we can hear.
Btw, my Think Pad notebook's charger does the same thing.

Comment: *In that case, there is nothing to worry about.* - I used to have a TV with this problem, and I was the only one able to hear it (only when the TV was off). And this thing was driving me crazy.

Comment: To add to this, a lot of people suffer from high-frequency hearing loss. It also depends on age and many other conditions. @EugeneSh. - seems like your high-frequency hearing ability is totally fine :)

Comment: @Whiskeyjack ...and to add to this: according to recent studies, the ear does not naturally lose performance based on age, but gets damaged during life due to exposure to high noise levels. Scientists found out, that the hearing of elderly of native tribes is as good as the hearing of the children of that tribe. So, it appears this is an effect of "modern living" where we are  exposed to noise very often.